# Angular 2 | NgformControl Prevents my NgModel from updating

Tags: typescript, angular, dropdown, angular2-ngmodel

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let reject of rejects, let i = index">
    <h2>{{reject.reason}}</h2>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="reject.reason" [ngFormControl]="inputField">
    <rt-dropdown (selectedReason)="selectReason($event.value, i)"></rt-dropdown>
</div>
```

and my mainTS:

```
class {
    inputField = new Control();


    constructor( private _broadcastService : BroadcastService) {
        this.inputField.valueChanges
           .debounceTime(300)
           .subscribe(term => this._dropdownComponent.query(term));
    }
}



selectReason(text, index) {
 this.rejects[index].reason = text;
}
```

RT-dropdown only sends a reason when you click on a reason.

The problem is, that when you click on a reason, the {{reject.reason}} changes, but the input field does not change.

It's like the page is not updating, anyone experience on this ?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you end up with 2 FormControl instances for a single component. Maybe you should remove the ngFormControl binding and inject it in your controller using `@VidewChild("input") input: NgFormControl` rather than instantiating a new one.

Comment: i followed Gunter Zochbauers answer to make a control per repeat( only needed 5 max, so works well!) thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let reject of rejects let idx=index">
    <h2>{{reject.reason}}</h2>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rejects[idx].reason" [ngFormControl]="inputField">
    <rt-dropdown (selectedReason)="selectReason($event.value, i)"></rt-dropdown>
</div>
```

You also need as many `inputField = new Control()` (maybe an array of `inputFields` as you have entries in `rejects` and refer to them in

```
[ngFormControl]="inputFields[idx]"
```

Otherwise all input elements refer to the same `Control` instance.

Comment: yes, this could be the problem, but how do i make an array of control objects ? just like inputFields = new Control()[]? that gives error somehow..

Comment: I didn't see how your `rejects` array is built. You could do `this.rejects.forEach(r => this.inputFields.push(new Control())` with `inputFields:Control[] = [];`

Comment: you are an Angular Genius ! thanks so much for the second time !

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let reject of rejects, let i = index">
  (...)
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rejects[i].reason" 
         [ngFormControl]="inputField">
</div>
```

**Edit**

I would use a control array for the corresponding controls:

```
let inputFieldControls = new ControlArray([]);

for(let i = 0 ; (...) ; i++){
  inputFieldControls.push(new Control('' , Validators.required));
}
```

and use it this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let reject of rejects, let i = index">
  (...)
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rejects[i].reason" 
         [ngFormControl]="inputFieldControls[i]">
</div>
```

Comment: you could try to use a control array for your controls. I updated my answer accordingly...